# Why doesn't TrafficStats.clearThreadStatsTag() work in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I don't mind resetting the TrafficStats value before launching the application. For this I use TrafficStats.clearThreadStatsTag(), but TrafficStats does not clear.
I know that TrafficStats is being reset. happens when the phone is rebooted
It is possible to reset TrafficStats. via code
I use Kotlin

I use TrafficStats.clearThreadStatsTag()